# Link 2 equivalent nodes using Cypher - neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Please be gentle, I'm a newbie with neo4j. 
I'm working on a media db and want to show political orientations similar in the US and other countries. Here I need a link between Left in France and Democrat US in the US

I searched and tried and ended up with this... unsuccessfully.

```
CREATE (r:PoliticalOrientation { name:'Democrat US' })-[:EQUIVALENT]->(r:PoliticalOrientation { name: 'Left' })
with r
MATCH (m:Media)-[:IS_LISTED_IN_CUSTOM_LISTS]->(p:CustomLists)
Match (m)-[:POLITICAL_ORIENTATION_IS]->(r:PoliticalOrientation)
WHERE p.name CONTAINS "NEWS" AND NOT r.name = "None"
RETURN m,r,p
```

Thanks for help and patience :)

Comment: In your first line both node variable is r! It's wrong.

Comment: Thanks Saeed. Changed both to t and u. Relationship is created but how can I have in the same graph: Media -> PoliticalOrientation and show the new relationship between Left and Democrats US?

Answer (score 1):

Your first error is in your first clause -- it should not be using the same variable name, `r`, for 2 different nodes.

*After fixing this error, you will also encounter others. But you have not provided enough details about what you are doing for any further help.*

Comment: Thanks Cybersam. I changed the variable names. No error. but I want is to graph media titles by their political orientation in both FR and the US and show the "equivalent" relationship in between similar parties in both countries, like Left (FR) and Democrats US (US)

Comment: Still not clear what your data model looks like, and what you are trying to do with it. I suggest that you try to solve on your own (without the first error), and if you still cannot solve it, create a new question with full details of your use case, neo4j data model, and with your new Cypher query.